# Largest strongly connected components of a directed graph

Tags: python, networkx, subgraph, connected-components

I am working on an `Networkx` `.MultiDiGraph()` object built from a total of 82927 directed email data. At current stage, I am trying to get the largest strongly connected components from the `.MultiDiGraph()` object and its corresponding subgraph.
The text data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pywfs60y8nbyquw/email.txt?dl=0).
Here's my working code:

```js
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
email_df = pd.read_csv('email_network.txt', delimiter = '->')
edge_groups = email_df.groupby(["#Sender", "Recipient"], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={"time":"weight"})
email = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edge_groups, '#Sender', 'Recipient', edge_attr = 'weight')
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(email.edges(data=True))

# G is a .MultiDiGraph object
# using .strongly_connected_components() to get the part of G that has the most nodes
# using list comprehension
number_of_nodes = [len(n) for n in sorted(nx.strongly_connected_components(G))]
number_of_nodes

# 'number_of_nodes' return a list of [1, 1, 1,...,1] of length 167 (which is the exact number of nodes in the network)

# using the recommended method in networkx documentation

largest = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)
largest

# 'largest' returns {92}, not sure what this means...
```

As I noted in the above code block, the list comprehension method returns a list of [1, 1, 1,..., 1] of length 167 (which is the total number of nodes in my data), while the `max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)` returned `{92}`, I am not sure what this means.

It looks like there's something wrong with my code and I might have missed several key steps in processing the data. Could anyone care to take a look at and enlighten me on this?

Thank you.

Note: Revised code (kudos to Eric and Joel)

```js
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
email_df = pd.read_csv('email_network.txt', delimiter = ' ')
edge_groups = email_df.groupby(["#Sender", "Recipient"], as_index=False).count().rename(columns={"time":"weight"})
# per @Joel's comment, adding 'create_using = nx.DiGraph()'     
email = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edge_groups, '#Sender', 'Recipient', edge_attr = 'weight', create_using = nx.DiGraph())
# adding this 'directed' edge list to .MultiDiGraph() object

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(email.edges(data=True))
```

We now examine the largest strongly connected component (in terms of the number of nodes) in this network.

```js
In [1]: largest = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)
In [2]: len(largest)
Out [2]: 126
```

The largest strongly connected component consists of 126 nodes.

[Updates]
Upon further trial and error, I found that one needs to use `create_using = .MultiDiGraph()` (instead of `.DiGraph()`) when loading data onto `networkx`, otherwise, even if you get correct number of nodes for your `MultiDiGraph` and its weakly/strongly connected subgraphs, you might still get the number of edges wrong! This will reflect in you `.strongly_connected_subgraphs()` outputs.

For my case here, I will recommend others to use this one-liner

```js
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.read_edgelist(path="email_network.txt", data=[('time', int)], create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph(), nodetype=str)
```

And we can implement `.strongly_connected_components(G)` and `strongly_connected_subgraphs` to verify.

If you use the `networkx` output `G` from the first code block, `max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)` will give an output with 126 nodes and 52xx something edges, but if you apply the one-liner I listed above, you will get:

```js
In [1]: largest = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)
In [2]: G_sc = max(nx.strongly_connected_subgraphs(G), key=len)

In [3]: nx.number_of_nodes(G_sc) 
Out [3]: 126
In [4]: nx.number_of_nodes(G_sc) 
Out [4]: 82130
```

You will get the same number of nodes with both methods but different number of edges owing to different counting mechanisms associated with different `networkx` graph classes.

Comment: I"ve found the mistake (I think).  Editing it into my answer now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying cause of your error is that `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` defaults to creating an undirected graph.  So `email` is an undirected graph.  When you then create the directed graph, each edge appears in only one direction.

To fix it use `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` with the argument `create_using = DiGraph`

---

**older comments related to the output you were getting**

All your strongly connected components have a single node.

When you do `max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)` it finds the set of nodes which has the longest length and returns it.  In your case, they all have length 1, so it returns one of them (I believe whichever networkx happened to put into `nx.strongly_connected_components(G)` first).  But it's returning the *set*, not the *length*.  So `{92}` is the set of nodes it is returning.

It happens that `{92}` was chosen to be the "longest" length 1 component in `nx.strongly_connected_components(G)` by the tiebreaker.

Example:

```
max([{1}, {3}, {5}], key = len)
> {1}
```

Comment: This has made me suspect if I have loaded and preprocessed my data correctly.

Comment: @ChrisT.: Your import is fine. I double-checked it.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out what seems to be wrong with this result. It just doesn't look 'normal.'

Comment: @ChrisT. I think I've now added the explanation of what you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks so much for addressing this, I am reading through your comments now.

Comment: Does the `create_using = DiGraph' also works with `create_using = MultiDiGraph`? Since I will be using MultiDiGraph(). It's nice to know that `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` has this option.

Comment: I got it. I should be blamed for the error. Thanks for pointing this this. I will add my revised code in the new edit section. Hope others will find this helpful.

Comment: Kudos for finding the solution! I cannot upvote you a second time. :-/

Comment: Glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 1, 1,...,1] of length 167 (which is the exact number of nodes in the network)
```

This means that there's basically no [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in your graph (except for lone vertices, that is).

If you sort those components by length, you get a randon component of one single vertex since the components all have the same length (`1`). In your example, `{92}`, which could have been any other vertex.

The import looks correct and there's really no strongly connected component, it means that nobody ever replied to any email.

To check if the problem doesn't come from `pandas`, `MultiDiGraph` or your import, I wrote:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

with open('email_network.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        n1, n2, time = line.split()
        if n1.isdigit():
            G.add_edge(int(n1),int(n2))
```

It didn't change the result.

Just adding an edge with `G.add_edge(2,1)` creates a large strongly connected component, though:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 126, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 128, 129, 134, 149, 151}
```

Comment: When  I verified it with `nx.is_strongly_connected(G)`, it returned a FALSE. But I just thought this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Joel   It has 3251 edges (some overlapped, hence, I added a 'weight' attribute to account for overlapping edges between the same pair of nodes).

Comment: ＠Eric, I guess what I really need is a better grouping function (I think my current one might be wrong). Because (and thanks so much for raising this), if you examine `email_df` by selecting part of the entries where `email_df[email_df[#Sender] == 2]`, then you will see Sender #2 actually sent back emails to Recipient #1 a couple times, hence, edge (2, 1) actually exists but was missing in the transformed `network` object.

Comment: No, I did not modify the original txt file.

Comment: @ChrisT. Now I'm really curious. Let's see tomorrow.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is the use of `create_using = nx.DiGraph()` in `nx.read_edgelist()` or `nx.from_pandas_dataframe()`. A friend was taking those online instruction courses during which one practices was to have them analyze directed multi-graph network, and he used `create_using = nx.DiGraph()` to read the data. Python gave him a `networkx` object that has the correct number of nodes but not the correct number of edges (at least not accepted by their auto-grader). I did try using `create_using = MultiDiGraph()` in my code, but it generated an error (saying it's unhashable).

Comment: @ChrisT I really don't understand what I did wrong yesterday. With the simple loop from my answer, a 126-vertices group component is found, either with `G = nx.DiGraph()` or `G = nx.MultiDiGraph()`. Anyway, your code's now working, so everything's fine!

Comment: I am still trying to figure out if my data was "actually" imported correctly. It seems that I really should specify `create_using = MultiDiGraph()` in the import stage, but I don't know where that error came from.... I mean, if one want to take a further step to do `strongly_connected_component_subgraphs()` on the largest connected component of G, then this will be an issue. If the data was imported correctly into `networkx`, then even if it has the correct number of nodes, their connectivity might not be correct. I am planning on opening another thread on this, will keep you guys posted.

Comment: I (think) I found out what's going with my code. I put revised code as new edit on the bottom of my original post. I need to read the documentation more thoroughly though.